# PHPExcel Date Format use like text

Tags: date, format, phpexcel

When I create a XLS file with PHPExcel, shows "fine" the date (12/15/2015) but when I copy and paste to another sheet, the format its lost. The cell format its "General" and use it like a text.

How can I make the Excel recognize the Date Format?

My code to assign format:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($var.$a)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2);
```

Comment: How are you writing this date to PHPExcel? Are you writing it as an Excel timestamp with a number format mask? Or simply as a string?

Comment: Look at `02types.php` in the `/Examples` folder to see how you should be setting date and time values

Comment: I looked the example and apply some correction, but didn't works.

Comment: Edit the question to show the code that you're using, and how you're actually setting the date value.... I can't guess what value you're storing in the cell if I can't see how you're doing it.... all I can do is guess that you're storing a string, not a serialized timestamp

Comment: I already edited yesterday.

Comment: All you're showing me is trying to set the ___style___ for the cell, nothing to do with trying to set the actual ___value___ of the cell.... it's the __value__ that you're setting that's wrong